# Using Apache Myfaces with Prime faces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, myfaces

I am new bie to JSF 2.0.

I am using the apache Myfaces implementation of JSF 2.0.

Also I want to use Prime faces for better UI components.

But the problem I am facing is:

The tags for both the `Prime faces and Myfaces` are same.

How do I resolves the prefixes.

For example: `h: and f:`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PrimeFaces does not have any tags in the `http://java.sun.com/jsf/*` namespace. It has only tags in the `http://primefaces.org/*` namespace. Tags in the `http://java.sun.com/jsf/*` namespace are part of the concrete JSF implementation which is in your case MyFaces. PrimeFaces is just a component library, not a JSF implementation. You are supposed to run PrimeFaces on top of a concrete JSF implementation.

So, once having both MyFaces and PrimeFaces in the webapp's runtime classpath, this should do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
>
    <h:head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h1>PrimeFaces editor demo</h1>
        <p:editor />
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Include primefaces by using the following
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"